# What happens when producer emits event to non-existent topic with auto-creation of topics disabled?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have seen this part of the documentation ([source](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_createtopic)):

> Let's create a topic named "test" with a single partition and only one replica:
>
> ```
> $ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
> ```
>
> We can now see that topic if we run the list topic command:
>
> ```
> $ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
> test
> ```
>
> Alternatively, instead of manually creating topics you can also configure your brokers to auto-create topics when a non-existent topic is published to.

It is not clear to me what happens if auto-creation of topics is not enabled, but a producer emits an event to a non-existing topic. Does it depend on the Client / Library? What are typical results?

(In case of code examples, I'd prefer Python)

Answer (score 7):

When a Kafka client (producer or consumer) connects to the bootstrap servers, the first thing it does is a metadata request: it asks for information about the topic partition it wants to produce or consume. If the `auto.create.topics.enable` is disabled, it gets an `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` error and cannot "use" the topic.
If you try to run the `kafka-console-producer` tool for example you will get the following:

```
[2018-12-28 08:59:37,669] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {my_topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-12-28 08:59:37,768] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {my_topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-12-28 08:59:37,869] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {my_topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-12-28 08:59:37,971] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {my_topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-12-28 08:59:38,073] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {my_topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

It means that a Kafka client will not even emit such an event, but throw an error even before that as the metadata request will fail earlier.